# phone notifications turned off by proximity to my computer?

Tags: iphone, notifications

Is there any way that my iphone can register that it's near enough to my mac to shut off notifications? I'd love to be able to get notifications for an email when I'm away from my computer, but just let my computer tell me when I'm near instead of hearing 2 different notification sounds. I understand I can turn off the ringer and have it work, but a proximity feature would be best. Example: I'm upstairs away from my computer, the alerts tells me that I have an email. 2 minutes later I go down by my computer and another email comes in, and my phone doesn't make a sound.

Comment: There's no stock, built-in way the iPhone and Mac know they're close to each other.  You'd need an app that uses bluetooth to determine proximity.  Have you tried any of those apps?

Comment: @fbara: could you mention some of those apps by name?